# Verifying that there is a piecewise linear function on a closed set that approximates it well

Tags: analysis

**Question:**  Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$.  Show that there is a piecewise linear function $\phi$ on $[a,b]$ with $|f(x)-\phi(x)| < \varepsilon$ for $x \in [a,b]$.

**My proof:** For any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta >0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x,y \in [a,b]$.  Let $b=a+N\delta$ and partition the interval into subintervals as follows: $x_n=a+n\delta$ for $n=1,2,3,...,N$.  Now let $f(x_i)=\phi(x_i)$ and let $\phi(x)$ be piecewise linear between $(x_i,x_{x+1})$.

Then for $x \in (x_i, x_{i+1})$:
$$|f(x)-\phi(x)|=|f(x)-f(x_k)+\phi(x_k)-\phi(x)|\leq|f(x)-f(x_k)|+|\phi(x_k)+\phi(x)| < 2\epsilon,$$
since
$$|x-x_k|<\delta.$$

Comment: What about $f$?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I'm not sure how to incorporate f's uniform continuity, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: No, Davide is pointing out that you never said what kind of function $f$ is. The question should begin with *Let* $f$ *be a continuous real-valued function on* $[a,b]$ or words to that effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably there should be a hypothesis that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. The argument is almost fine. The one slight hiccup is your assumption that $b-a$ is an integral multiple of $\delta$. After you use continuity of $f$ and compactness of $[a,b]$ to get a $\delta$ that ‘works’ for that $\epsilon$, you want to choose $N$ large enough so that $(b-a)/N<\delta$ and then replace $\delta$ by $(b-a)/N$.

Comment: Do you mean that I want to replace the $\delta$ in $a+n\delta$ with $a+n\frac{b-a}{N}$?


Also, thanks for noting that I left off a meaningful part of the problem...the continuity of f.

Comment: @EMKA: Yes. Or use unif. cont. to say that there is a $\delta_0>0$ such that etc., then choose $N$ so that $\frac{b-a}N\le\delta_0$, let $\delta=\frac{b-a}N$, and leave it as is.

Comment: Continuity $f$  on compact set $[a,\,b]$ implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous .